# how to get the direction of a location in google map api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i want to get the Direction of location in lati longi

when i use google map api

then he return me lati long for city (27.19, 78.01) but i need position too

means N E W S how i can get them too like

```
(27.19 N , 78.01 E).
```

N for north and E for east. how i can get the flank or direction too.

Answer (score 2):

If the latitude returned by Googles Maps API is a positive number, then it is N.  If it is negative, then it is S.

If the longitude is positive, then it is E.  If it is negative, then it is W.

Answer (score 0):

**One can easily calculate distance between two location with the help of Google Map APIs.** Google Map APIs comes with a set of classes which helps in doing such tasks.
**class GDirection**, helps in getting the travel distance between the two different location.

check following link for its example :-
http://tajendrasengar.blogspot.com/2011/09/distance-between-two-locations-with.html